# Contar dentro de Grupby

Tags: laravel

necesito contar donde Estado sea == 1, como sería la expresión correcta?

```
$array = Reservas::groupBy('rrpp')->selectRaw('rrpp, count(*) as cantidad, count(*) as estado')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo así, si estoy entendiendo bien la pregunta

```
      ->selectRaw('rrpp, count(*) as cantidad, SUM(IF(estado=1,1,0)) as estado1_conteo)
```